# Is there any script in php which scans the code and return

Tags: php, traversal

Is there any script in php which scans the code and return variables dependancy? at least provide me some algorithm.

I am creating web application auditor, where I want to scan code from it's source (like $_POST, $_GET etc) to sink (like echo , print etc). for that I want to traverse through the code . I have tokens but I am not getting any idea to do it.?

for e.g.

```
function abc($apple,$banana,$mango=FALSE)
{
   $fruit = $apple;
   $fav = $fruit;
    echo $fav;
}
```

in this I want to get an array which tells me $apple is main variable and $fruit, $fav are dependant on it.

Comment: [PHP Parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser)

Comment: [PHPPHP](https://github.com/ircmaxell/PHPPHP) perhaps?